# How to get angular project folder path from visual studio code extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, angular6, angular7

I am trying to get currently opened file project folder path in VS Code.I have lot of angular project.If i am opening in my vs code how can i find project folder path.Any way is there..Can i use node_modules folder name? or Can i get project folder name using node_modules folder name for parent folder name like that? Any one kown please help me.

```
var vscode = require("vscode");
var path = require("path");
function activate(context) {

//How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/tree if i open tree?
//How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/water if i open water?
//How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/rain if i open rain?

   var currentlyOpenfileprojectname = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath;  

}
```

projects folder paths:

```
c://mamp/htdocs/projects/tree
c://mamp/htdocs/projects/water
c://mamp/htdocs/projects/rain
```

Opened VS Code folder structure:

```
projects -   

   tree
     -e2e
     -node_modules
     -src
   water
     -e2e
     -node_modules
     -src
   rain
     -e2e
     -node_modules
     -src
```

How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/tree if i open tree?
How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/water if i open water?
How can i get project path like c://mamp/htdocs/project/rain if i open rain?